# DLL load failed, %1 is not a valid win32 application

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

Having some problems using an f2py module that I built using the following code:

```
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension

ext = Extension(name = 'Sigma',
                 sources = ['Sigma.f95'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(name = 'f2py_example',
        ext_modules =[ext])
```

The following module file is created as well as the following DLL file:

```
Sigma.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
libSigma.5AWJEGTYYIR7CSGZ2JEOIYO7P5ZGQKVC.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
```

Yet when I import the pyd file into python I get the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

As far as I know I have both 64bit python and said dll and pyd file are both 64bit, it might be the gfortran compiler but I cant find a 64 bit version, any help would be much appreciated.

I have now since got a 64-bit gfortran compiler but it is still not working

I have just checked the dll file and it says that it is actually 32bit not 64bit how would I change this? is it still the compiler issue?